# Google Analytics with Cordova/Phonegap

Tags: ios, cordova, google-analytics

I am attempting to implement Google Analytics with a Cordova/Phonegap application, mostly for the crash logs/error reporting functionality.

In the Google Analytics setup guide, I am on the step that implements most of the GA interfaces into the UIController. The problem I am having is that, because I am implementing Cordova, my MainUIController does not implement the generic UIViewController, but rather the Cordova UI controller. I am not an objective-c developer, but I do know that Objective-C does not support multiple inheritance.

Is there an "best way" to do what I am trying to do?

For reference, the guide says change this:

```
@interface HomeViewController : UIViewController
```

To this:

```
#import "GAITrackedViewController.h"

@interface HomeViewController : GAITrackedViewController
```

But my controller looks like this:

```
@interface MainViewController : CDVViewController
```

Thoughts?